# How to set timer in draw Graphics in object class

Tags: java, timer

first, sorry for my grammar. i need to create Bomb object and paint black and 5 second later it will paint in red without freezing my game, i try to make Bomber Man game. Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Bomb {
    int x,y;
    int block = 60;
    public Bomb(int x,int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(this.x * block, this.y * block, block, block);
        if ( /*TIMER == 0*/) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(this.x * block, this.y * block, block, block);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Comment: @VGR i dont know how to combine with my code, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do more than just change the color of your Bomb object.  Your game needs to keep track of the Bomb’s state.  Therefore, you need to create a Timer in a different class, and have that Timer’s action listener change an attribute of the Bomb which the Bomb class uses to determine how it paints:

```
public class Bomb {
    boolean expired;

    // ...

    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(expired ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(this.x * block, this.y * block, block, block);
    }
}
```

Whatever class controls your game’s logic will need to create a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) whenever it creates a Bomb:

```
Bomb bomb = new Bomb(x, y);
Timer timer = new Timer(10_000, e -> {
    bomb.expired = true;
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```